# How to Display Coordinates of an Existing Point Layer in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have been asked to provide a list of coordinates for a point layer in our GIS.  I am currently using a state plane coordinate system.  How do I view/list this data.  Below is the data request in it's original form: (Each serial number is assigned to a specific city address)

If I were to provide you with a list of ONT serial numbers like this one:

```
Serial Number Lon Lat
S050731154  
S031620362  
S022960010  
S030560404  
S021860376  
S043371128  
S032140857  
S030490038  
S023080296  
S022380211  
S030150116  
S023080386  
S043371132
```

Would you be able to fill in the longitude and latitude of the ONT owning that serial number based on the data stored within the GIS?

Or on the other hand, do you have the ability to export such a list?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using ArcGIS you can generate XY columns for the data using the Add XY Coordinates tool in ArcToolbox.  Open ArcToolbox, then go to the Data Management Tools>Features toolbox.  This will add an X and Y column to your data a populate them. You can then export to a table if that is what's required.

Comment: When I run this in ArcToolbox I get the following error message: "Either beig edited or in use by another application".  At the time that I ran this I did not have ArcGIS open.....what gives?

Comment: If you are working in ArcCatalog and had been previewing the layer, Catalog is probably locking the layer.  Close and reopen Catalog then use the tool without previewing the layer.  That has worked for me in the past.

Comment: I used this today & it worked famously.  Thanks Zachary (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use python field calculator script for **Point** features.

To get X value use --`!SHAPE.FirstPoint.X!`

To get Y value use --`!SHAPE.FirstPoint.Y!`

[image: Field]

N.B. This comes very much handy when you need to get start and end X,Y of **Lines**. as below

To get start X value of line use --`!SHAPE.FirstPoint.X!`

To get start Y value of line use --`!SHAPE.FirstPoint.Y!`

To get end X value of line use --`!SHAPE.LastPoint.X!`

To get end Y value of line use --`!SHAPE.LastPoint.Y!`

Comment: Slow!  And same invalid results as the Generate XY tool.  Selecting the "Calculate Geometry..." tool just below this one did work, though.

Comment: @ ca0V  Ah!, I just tested and found this does not give wrong values.